# Значение словосочетания «культурный шлейф»

Tags: словосочетания, фразеология

Может ли кто-то точно объяснить, что оно означает? Казалось бы, шлейф — само слово указывает на некую вторичность или на какое-то следование в фарватере определённого культурного явления. Но вот несколько цитат, содержащих это выражение, и вот они-то окончательно сбивают меня с толку. Хотя в первой есть даже частичное разъяснение.

> *«Временнýю глубину концепту придают примыкающие к понятийному уровню **шлейфы** — генетический, **историко-культурный**, интертекстуальный. […] **Историко-культурный шлейф** складывается из фрагментов знаний о прежних реальных воплощениях концепта, его языковым отражением служат историзмы и некоторые прецедентные имена, под которыми хранятся в памяти образцы и выделяющиеся примеры (Дж. Лакофф), как, например, царь, Советы, империя, Сталин в историко-культурном шлейфе концепта «государство». Немалую часть паремий можно отнести к регулятивной зоне историко-культурного шлейфа…» (О. Евтушенко, «Художественная речь как инструмент познания»).*

Тут достаточно понятно, но для нижеприведённых цитат такая трактовка не вполне годится.

> *«Пожалуй, самая престижная выставочная площадка в России — это зал на «Беговой» МОСХа в Москве. Его **культурный шлейф** из профессиональных и человеческих страстей не только меняет восприятие, но и погружает в какой-то тихий, чуть приметный транс» («Творческий союз художников России», http://www.tcxp.ru/articles/bronzovyy-gost ).*
>
> *«Слово, транслируемое книгой, постоянно изменяло своё значение и **культурный шлейф**, оно вступало во взаимодействие внутри возникавших медиа и изменяло медиапространство» (К. Костюк, «Книга в новой медийной среде»).*
>
> *«…И рок — это стихия нашей свободы, это наша музыкальная культура. И вот так у неё получилось воедино связать понятие вот такой музыкальной свободы, некой нашей идеологии такой внутренней, современной музыки и того **культурного шлейфа**, и того духа братства, который мы хотели бы видеть в нашей организации» (Из интервью Н. Коледина в телепередаче «Рассвет»).

Дело в том, что я затрудняюсь заменить этот «культурный шлейф» синонимичным словом или словосочетанием, не совсем понимая, что имеется в виду. Прошу разъяснить, кто знает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шлейф-многозначное слово:

1. длинный, волочащийся сзади подол женского платья
2. геол. полоса отложений, окаймляющая подножье возвышенности
3. перен. след, полоса от движения чего-либо
4. перен. ряд каких-либо действий, последствий

и ещё 2 значения,которые нам ничего не дают в данных примерах.

У второго значения (полоса отложений) тоже есть переносное - пласт событий. Вот как шлейф культурного слоя - пласт с археологическими находками одного времени, так и шлейф культурных событий.

В 4 значении употреблено сочетание шлейф культурных инноваций:"Проникновение на территорию Кавказа носителей урукских традиций в IV тысячелетии до н.э. повлек за собой целый шлейф культурных инноваций".

В Ваших примерах:

1.«Временнýю глубину концепту придают примыкающие к понятийному уровню шлейфы — генетический, историко-культурный, интертекстуальный. […] ***Историко-культурный шлейф*** складывается из фрагментов знаний о прежних реальных воплощениях концепта, его языковым отражением служат историзмы и некоторые прецедентные имена, под которыми хранятся в памяти образцы и выделяющиеся примеры (Дж. Лакофф)... Историко-культурный **шлейф**=историко-культурный **пласт**.

2."...зал на «Беговой» МОСХа в Москве. Его культурный шлейф из профессиональных и человеческих страстей не только меняет восприятие, но и погружает в какой-то тихий, чуть приметный транс» («Творческий союз художников России», http://www.tcxp.ru/articles/bronzovyy-gost ).**Культурный шлейф = содержание, наполнение культурного пласта.** Но есть и оттенок значения **"след", "ряд чего-то, каких-то последствий как хвост"**, ведь в тихий транс погружает атмосфера выставочного зала, полоса человеческих страстей, которая тянется как некий туманный хвост.

«Слово, транслируемое книгой, постоянно изменяло своё значение и **культурный шлейф**(т.е. культурное **содержание**, тот же **пласт**), оно вступало во взаимодействие внутри возникавших медиа и изменяло медиапространство» (К. Костюк, «Книга в новой медийной среде»).

*«…И рок — это стихия нашей свободы, это наша музыкальная культура. И вот так у неё получилось воедино связать понятие вот такой музыкальной свободы, некой нашей идеологии такой внутренней, современной музыки и того **культурного шлейфа** (культурного содержания,наполнения, **пласта**)

Answer (score 0):

Культурный шлейф - это выражение всегда было синонимом выражения "культурный след" и я еще ни разу в текстах не встречал иного его смыслового трактования. Это лишь игра слов и никакого дополнительного смысла.